# Can you say that something "interferes with someone's doing something"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

In a gerund and infinitive [exercise](https://perriced.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/unit-9-grammar.pdf), there is the following conversation:

> Annie: My parents finally bought me a new TV, but it has a V-chip.
>
> Bea: What's that?
>
> Annie: It's something that blocks violent shows so that I can't watch
>   them.
>
> Summary: **A V-chip interferes with Annie's watching violent shows.**

Having studied English for a long time, I find the usage of the verb *interfere* in this context to be cringe worthy and unheard of. I want to know if I am wrong and if I could use the verb "interfere" in such context.

I have looked it up in many dictionaries, there is no sentence example or a sense that I found that the word interfere  could come in such context. It could be used such as in these sentences:

> Smoking and drinking alcohol interferes with your body's ability to
>   process oxygen.
>
> Anxiety interferes with children's performance at school.

Comment: Have you looked up *interfere* in a dictionary? I think you will find that this sense, "obstruct, hinder", is the word's central meaning. You may be misled by the non-central use of *interfere* in BrE as a euphemism for sexual assault.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with _interfere_ in that sentence. The Saxon genitive with the gerund is pretty gnarly, though. What is it that makes you think _interfere_ is wrong here?

Comment: @StoneyB, I did. I edited my question.

Comment: In both of the uses you cite something interferes with somebody--your body, children--doing something. The only difference is that in your questioned sentence *watching* is a gerund (a verbform which acts as a noun), not a frank noun.

Comment: But when the word interfere comes in that sense, it almost always comes with a noun, not a gerund. That's why I said it sounds awkward. I have never listened or read the word interfere to be used when a gerund comes after. I want to know how common or used this use of gerund after the word interfere.

Comment: @GhaithAlrestom A gerund _is_ a noun: it's the noun form of the verb. With _interfere,_ the usage is not remarkable at all. _"Painful bunions interfere with walking and exercising."_ ... _"New research by Professor Michael Morris explores the process through which reminders of one's home culture can interfere with speaking a second language."_

Comment: @P.E.Dant All those sentences sound natural. Interfere means affecting something adversely. But in the original sentence, if V-chip prevents Annie from watching violent shows, then it doesn't interfere with her watching them. It doesn't affect her watching violent shows. It blocks them, prevents them. It just seems to me that interfere is a poor choice of word.

Comment: @GhaithAlrestom _Interfere_ may not be as good a choice as _prevent,_ but it is perfectly understandable and applicable in that sentence; _preventing_ her from watching is a way of _interfering_ with her action. A native speaker would not see anything amiss in this usage of _interfere._ The whole sentence is misbegotten, though, and I'm not sure that "Dave's Advanced Grammar" is a very good source in general.

Comment: @GhaithAlrestom I'm with the others and while *interfere* isn't the *best* word to use in this context, it's not inherently wrong.  I think you might be sensing the overall clumsiness of the entire sentence, and not just that word choice.

Answer (score 1):

*Interfere* implies that the action or goal being interfered with was desired by whoever was doing it, is desirable, or is supposed to happen.

> Tommy interfered with my study time (You wanted to study)
>
> Smoking and drinking alcohol interferes with your body's ability to process oxygen (Processing oxygen is desirable)
>
> Anxiety interferes with children's performance at school (We want children to perform well at school)

So this does sound weird:

> A V-chip interferes with Annie's watching violent shows.

except that the person saying probably doesn't want Annie to watch violent shows, so in a greater context it's probably OK.